# Application for supplementary items with filtering - Python?

Tags: python, excel, windows, filtering

**I CAN RESIGN FROM PYTHON**

I have tough task ahead and I kinda don't know how to approach it.

I want to make an app that has two windows inside.
In each window there's some data (let's say excel file with about 30 columns and 300k records. - SAME DATA FOR BOTH WINDOWS)

Idea is to let users pick index from left window and right window (by some kind checkbox?) and then generate appropriate excel file.

My biggest problem is how to approach letting users filter columns in each window in excel like manner (is python even good for that ?) and how to let users check indexes from each window to later generate appropriate row in output file.

Please if you have any experience share with me :) I'd be grateful.
[image]

Comment: pandas is a good python library for data handling however you will have a hard time creating a perfect user interface using only python, if you don't really care about visual aspect, you could couple it with a python UI framework, for example Kivy

Comment: However creating your user interface is not straightforward, pagination, ordering, selection will be needed for such table and you don't really want to recreate excel. Maybe you should consider a browser rendering and use the tremondous amount of work created to handle such case, For example look at https://primeng.org/table and what can be done with minimal number of line